# PHP, PDO, Form, Update User Class Not Working As Expected

Tags: php, class, pdo

I have a php user class to add, remove, update users. On the update function it's not returning any errors, it returns success but the actual database values are not changing.

Any ideas?

This is my user.class.php file.

```
public function userUpdate($id, $fname, $lname) {
  $pdo = $this->pdo;
  if (isset($id) && !empty($id) && isset($fname) && !empty($fname) && isset($lname) && !empty($lname)) {
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET fname = ?, lname = ? WHERE id = ?');
  if ($stmt->execute([$id, $fname, $lname])) {
    $this->msg = 'User name was successfully updated!';
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    $this->msg = 'User name failed to update!';
    return false;
  }
  }
  else
  {
    $this->msg = 'Data lost or not set!';
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is my update.func.php file.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (isset($_POST['uid']) && !empty($_POST['uid']) && 
    isset($_POST['fname']) && !empty($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) && !empty($_POST['lname'])) {
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'uid', FILTER_DEFAULT);
    $fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    if ($user->userUpdate($id, $fname, $lname)) {
      header('Location: https://domain/update.php?result=pass&message=' . $user->getMsg());
      exit;
    }
    else
    {
      header('Location: https://domain/update.php?result=fail&message=' . $user->getMsg());
      exit;
    }
  }
  else
  {
      header('Location: https://domain/update.php?result=fail&message=' . $user->getMsg());
  }
}
else
{
    header('Location: https://domain/update.php?result=fail&message=' . $user->getMsg());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the parameters in the wrong order in execute here:

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET fname = ?, lname = ? WHERE id = ?');
  if ($stmt->execute([$id, $fname, $lname])) {
```

You need to pass them as:

```
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET fname = ?, lname = ? WHERE id = ?');
  if ($stmt->execute([$fname, $lname, $id])) {
```

Comment: Additionally I suggest instead of doing the XSS filtering on input, that you do it on output. Otherwise you risk mangling data.

Comment: Just tried this and was unsuccessful. Thank's for the suggestion!

Comment: as @coladict stated, there are very few cases where filtering/sanitizing on input is necessary, it should most usually be done on output.

Comment: @Intelacyber then perhaps you should try individual `$stmt->bindValue()` calls, then an `execute()` call without parameters. I vaguely remember having a problem with PDO that was solved that way.